# Passing Laravel Route Parameter to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, parameters, datatables

I'm using server-side DataTables in Laravel ([Yajra](https://datatables.yajrabox.com) to be specific).

I have a route set up that pulls all assets and returns as a DataTable, but what I need is to pull all assets where the school_id is equal to the parameter in the URL.

So my application should look like this:

- User lands on /schools/{school_id}/assets .e.g schools/1/assets
- Datatables pulls all school's assets using that {school_id}

I'm using the following so far in the script:

```
$(function() {
    $('#assets-table').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: '/api/assets',
        columns: [
            {data: 'asset_tag', name: 'assets.asset_tag'},
            {data: 'name', name: 'assets.name'},
        ]
    });
});
```

What would be the best approach to fetching that ID in the URL and passing it to that ajax request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer will reflect a method I use to have all files structured and don't mix `blade` files with `js`.

In your controller you will have the the `{school_id}`. You could simply pass it to the blade as so:

```
return view('...')->with([
  'school_id' => $school_id
]);
```

Create a simple `input` field to be able to fetch the data.

```
<input type="hidden" data-fetch-route="{{ route('name_of_route', ['school_id' => $school_id]) }}" id="schoolFetch">
```

In the `.js` file you can have:

```
$(function() {
 $('#assets-table').DataTable({
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: $("#schoolFetch").attr('data-fetch-route'),
    columns: [
        {data: 'asset_tag', name: 'assets.asset_tag'},
        {data: 'name', name: 'assets.name'},
    ]
});
```

As you could see you will have `route('name_of_route', ['school_id' => $school_id])` which means you will need to accept a parameter at the route `name_of_route`

If you would like to go even deeper and cleaner you can create a file called `utilities.js` and this file will have all the functions that you may use all over your application as such:

```
window.getRoute = function($element, action){
  return $element.attr('data-' + action + '-route');
}
```

and

```
ajax: $("#schoolFetch").attr('data-fetch-route'),
```

will turn into

```
ajax: getRoute($("#schoolFetch"), 'fetch'),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $('#assets-table').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: {{ route('name.your.route.here') }},
        columns: [
            {data: 'asset_tag', name: 'assets.asset_tag'},
            {data: 'name', name: 'assets.name'},
        ]
    });
});
```